# Finding limit of $p$-norm of succession of functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $\,f,g \in L^{p} ( \mathbb R^{n} ,\mathcal{L}, m)$, $\mathcal{L}$ being the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets and $m$ being the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$. Now, for $1\le p < \infty$ find the value of $\lim\limits_{|x|_{n} \to \infty} \|f(x+x_{n}) + g(x-x_{n})\|_{p}$.

My thoughts:

Since the space of all simple measurable functions with zero space of finite measure is dense in $L^{p}(\mathbb R^{n},\mathcal{L},m)$, if we take two such functions $f, g$ then as $|x_{n}| \to \infty$ $f(x+x_{n}) $ and $g(x-x_{n})$ will have disjoint compact support, and by the translation invariance of Lebesgue Measure in $\mathbb R^{n}$ the limit value should be $\|f\|_{p} + \|g\|_{p}$.

Now, please check my idea and rectify if necessary. But what I need mostly, because I think my thought out solution is correct, is a formal proof! Beacuse I am confused about how to write this proof! Thank you!

Comment: Are my arguments wrong???

Comment: So we have two Lebesgue-$L^p$ functions $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. $p$ is a number such that $1\leq p<\infty$. Surely $\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p$ is greater than or equal to that value, since by triangular inequality we have $\|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)\|_p\leq\|f(x+x_n)\|_p+\|g(x-x_n)\|_p$, but integrating on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes the shifted argument irrelevant and that is precisely $\|f\|_p+\|g\|_p$. Now we are wondering what happens when $|x_n|\to\infty$, where by $|x_n|$ I assume you mean some norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which one doesn't matter since they are all topologically equivalent).

Comment: As you say, the space of all simple measurable functions with zero space of finite measure is dense in $L^p$. That is because we can surely approximate any $L^p$ function with a succession of simple functions, and any of those can be approximated, if it has infinite zero space, by a succession of ones with finite measure zero space - if by "zero space" you mean $\{x:f(x)=0\}$. In particular, if the approximated function is positive, the succession is non-decreasing, and so the limit passes under the integral.

Comment: I don't think we need the finite measure zero space requirement though :). Suppose first that $f_m\to f$ and $g_m\to f$ for $m\to\infty$. Then clearly $f_m(x+x_n)+g_m(x-x_n)\uparrow f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)$. The inequalities and convergence are preserved by the norms, by monotony of the integral and of the power function (the norm is $p$-th root of integral of absolute value to the $p$, absolute value is the function because they are positive, integral and $p$-th power and root are monotonic), and by the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Disclaimer: the above is just an attempt, I don't know if I will be able to complete it. That's why I am not posting an answer, but comments. It may just be a starting point for you :).

Comment: So if we can say something about the value of the limit for the $f_m(x+x_n)+g_m(x-x_n)$, then we may conclude something on that of your question. Thinking on it, taking the $f_m,g_m$ may even not be necessary. After all, $f,g\in L^p$, so $m(\{f(x)\neq0\})<+\infty$, as is $m(\{g(x)\neq0\})$. When you write $f(x+x_n)$, you are essentially shifting the whole graph of the function $f$ by $-x_n$. If we fix a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can see that beyond a certain $n$ we must have $f(x+x_n)=0$, because the zeroes at infinity are coming in. So $f(x+x_n)$ converges to zero pointwise. (…)

Comment: (…) The same argument holds for $g(x-x_n)$, save that you are shifting the graph by $+x_n$. But that is irrelevant since our concern is the $L^p$ norm. Your argument appears correct. Let's see. My visual idea of shifting the graph combined with the zeroes can be used to say that, at a certain point, the supports of the two functions will be disjoint. More formally, calling $A$ the support of $f$ and $B$ the support of $g$, it is evident that the support of $f(x+x_n)$ is $A_n=A-x_n$ and that of $g(x-x_n)$ is $B_n=B+x_n$. Let me have dinner, then I will finish - hopefully :).

Comment: Let us take two points $x\in A_n,\,y\in B_n$. They will be $a-x_n$ and $b+x_n$ for some $a\in A,\,b\in B$, admitting the expression of the shifted supports is correct. Their distance is then $|a-x_n-(b+x_n)|=|a-b-2x_n|\geq|a-b|-2|x_n|\geq d(A,B)-2|x_n|$. This doesn't give anything since the right side tends to infinity for $|x_n|\to\infty$. Let me work on the triangular inequality. $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$, where $a,b$ are generic, not the $a,b$ above. Writing $a=x-y$ and $b=y$, we have $|x|\leq|x-y|+|y|\implies|x|-|y|\leq|x-y|$. By symmetry, we can put an absolute value on the left side.

Comment: With this in mind, the inequality $|a-b-2x_n|\geq d(A,B)-2|x_n|$ can be written with an absolute value on the right side, meaning that $2|x_n|-d(A,B)\leq|a-b-2x_n|$. Now the left side tends to $+\infty$, which means the right side also does, so for any fixed two points $a\in A,\,b\in B$ the corresponding points in the shifted supports have distance tending to infinity. This means there must be $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which all distances are non-zero, which implies the sets are disjoint.

Comment: I guess I can now give you a value for the limit, meaning I will post an answer summing up all this.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\xint}{\int\limits}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
As the comments state, if $f,g$ are two Lebesgue-$L^p$ functions, surely their supports $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ are of finite measure. If we take $f_n(x):= f(x+x_n)$ for some $x_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we can conclude the support $A_n$ of $f_n$ is $A-x_n$. Indeed take a point $x\in A$. That means $f(x)\neq0$. If we take $x-x_n$, then $f_n(x-x_n)=f(x-x_n+x_n)=f(x)\neq0$, so $x-x_n\in A_n$. Therefore $A-x_n\subseteq A_n$. Viceversa, let $x\in A_n$. Then $f_n(x)\neq0$ But $f_n(x)=f(x+x_n)$, so $x+x_n\in A\implies x\in A-x_n$. Thus, $A_n\subseteq A-x_n$, which combined with the other inclusion gives an equality. A similar argument shows that letting $g_n(x):=g(x-x_n)$ we obtain that the support $B_n$ of $g_n$ is $B+x_n$. Summing up, we have:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
A_n=A-x_n \\
B_n=B+x_n
\end{array}\right. \quad\quad\ast$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x\in A_n,\,y\in B_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $x=a-x_n$ for $a\in A$ and $y=b+x_n$ for $b\in B$, by $\ast$. So their distance is $|x-y|=|(a-x_n)-(b+x_n)|=|a-b-2x_n|$. Now as said in the comments from the triangular equality $|x|\leq|x-y|+|y|$, and carrying $|y|$ to the left and applying an argument of symmetry yields $|\|x\|-\|y\||\leq\|x-y\|$, where I had to use $\|\|$ to avoid confusing the norm with the absolute value. If we apply this above we get:
$$d(x,y)=|x-y|=|a-b-2x_n|\geq2|x_n|-d(A,B),$$
where $d(A,B)$ is the infimum of $d(a,b)$. So fixing any $(a,b)\in A\times B$, the shifted points are further apart than $|x_n|-d(A,B)$, which tends to infinity for $n\to\infty$. This means that for all $(a,b)\in A\times B$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a-x_n,b+x_n)>0$ strictly. Since $|x_n|\uparrow+\infty$, we can find an $n$ as above described such that the strict positivity holds for all $m\geq n$. Note that the inequality above holds for all couples, meaning the supremum of such $n$ is necessarily finite. This implies that, for $n$ sufficiently big, $A_n\cap B_n=\varnothing$, where by "sufficiently big" I clearly mean "greater than or equal to that supremum". Since we are taking the limit, we are not interested in what happens before the supremum. So we can, without any loss of generality, assume that supremum is 1. This is merely to write what follows without repeating "for $n$ etc" every time. Let's see the norm. Inside it we have an integral. Obviously, integrating over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as integrating over the support of the integrand. But that support is $A_n\cup B_n$, which is a disjoint union, and the integral is additive over the integration domain. So we can write:
$$\|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)\|_p=\sqrt[p]{\xint_{A_n\cup B_n}|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)|^p\mathrm{d}m}=$$ $$=\sqrt[p]{\xint_{A_n}|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)|^p\mathrm{d}m+\xint_{B_n}|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)|^p\mathrm{d}m}.$$
Now the disjointness of the two supports also implies the first integral reduces to that of $|f(x+x_n)|^p$, since $g(x-x_n)$ is zero, and the second one analogously reduces to that of $|g(x-x_n)|^p$. By translation invariance of $m$, we get that those two integrals are the $p$-th powers of the $p$-norms:
$$\|f(x+x_n)+g(x-x_n)\|_p=\sqrt[p]{\|f\|_p^p+\|g\|_p^p}.$$
Now that very rarely reduces to the sum of the $p$-norms, except for the trivial cases when one of the norms (or both) is 0 or $p=1$. So your arguments were correct, but you conclusion wasn't careful enough. Of course, the limit value you gave is greater than or equal to this one: just take the $p$-th powers and see the extra terms on the side of your limit, which are all positive since they are positive-coefficient products of norms, which are non-negative. Note that this *is* a limit, since the disjointness and all that follows only holds for $n$ above the supremum above mentioned.

**Edit:** I wasn't too explicit on this, but the fact that the $p$-norms of the shifted functions are all equal to those of the unshifted ones is due to the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure, which grants the equality for the integrals, as can be seen by the definition with the repartition function. You can easily add details to this, I take it.

**Edit 2:** In fact, I just realized there *are* $L^p$ functions with infinite support, meaning it is not compact, as you assumed, but most relevantly that the supremum above is in fact $+\infty$. If you opportunely connect $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ and $x^2+y^2$, for example, you can easily see by switching to polar coordinates that the resulting function is $L^p$ for any $p$. However, it is never zero. The above limit holds only if the supremum is finite, because otherwise the supports of the shifted functions are never disjoint. I guess, however, it can still be a good approximation of the actual limit, since for very big $n$'s the intersection of the supports is a place where both shifted functions are really close to zero. That is required by the $L^p$ condition, so in general the limit wil be a little greater than the $p$-th root of the sum of the $p$-th powers of the $p$ norms. When it is not equal, you can give a range of values for the limit, since it is less than the sum of the $p$ norms as I showed in a comment somewhere.